# Dependency error Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, npm

I'm having trouble running this old project. I'll update it after i managed to open it.

i get this message when i do ./gradlew build

[image: error i got]

this is my build.gradle

[image: build.gradle]

the build.gradle in react-native-camera

[image: react-native-camera]

nothing seems to work. how can i resolve and run this app?

Thank you in advance!

I've tried to change the build.gradle in the react-native-camera to make it match with the android one. I've also added the react-native version to the android\app\build.gradle

[image: android\app\build.gradle]

as i saw in another SO question.

when i try to launch npm install i get this

[image: npm install error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the react-native-camera library and it worked